# Xamarin.iOS: Object Disposed but Memory Not Reclaiming

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a straightforward `UIPageViewController` with 30 pages where each page has a `UIImageView` (and accompanying `UIImage` which is loaded with `UIImage.FromFile(..)`). I ensured that there are no references to any of the pages being held in memory (or by the `UIPageViewDataSource`) once the user navigates forward through the pages.

What I'm seeing is that when the user navigates forward, the destructor and `Dispose(bool)` methods are being called for the `UIViewController` of each page and for the `UIImageView` within the page (as expected). However, when I run this test on hardware attached to Instruments, even though the `IDisposable` methods are being called, the memory is not being reclaimed. After a certain threshold of "live bytes" is reached, a lot of the memory consumed by the pages which have been garbage collected is then reclaimed:

[image: Instruments screenshot illustrating the problem]

Why am I not seeing the memory being reclaimed immediately (i.e. when the `IDisposable` methods are called)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few reasons for this (see [New Dispose Semantics](http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/MonoTouch_6/MonoTouch_6.0/#MonoTouch_6.0.8) documentation).

They are mostly related to the fact that you call `Dispose` when you (the application) is done with the **managed** instance of the an object.

However it does not mean that iOS itself is done with the **native** object and it could very well try to callback into **managed** code (e.g. subclasses, events). This is not easy to predict unless you have a very good knowledge of the lifecycle of the objects involved (and any error would result in crashes).

Note that even before this change (in 6.0.8) the only thing that `Dispose` could release was the managed instance memory - which is, for most objects, very small compared to it's native size counterpart.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there anyway for me to **completely** control when iOS disposes the native objects? Lets say I'm planning on having some really large objects which I know for sure are no longer needed and is guaranteed not to call back any managed code.

Comment: Not really, ObjC use reference counting (so never free yourself). As long as some other object(s) do not release your object you cannot safely free it (it will be freed only when no one has a reference to it). *In some cases* you might be able to `nil` some property (e.g. in a parent view) to it will stop retaining your instance (but that will vary on a case-by-case basis).

Comment: Something that helps me with these disposal issues is removing any programmatically added subviews, disposing them, and setting them to null when I am done with the view.